# Return only part of string in linqQuery

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm having this linqQuery with reurns a list of blogposts

```
var blogPosts = _repo.GetPosts().OrderByDescending(o => o.PostedOn).Take(25).ToList();
```

In my class I'm having a string propery called Description witch contains a very long text.
My question is, how can I within the linqQuery include some code that says it should only return the first 20 letters from my `public string Description { get; set; }`

Comment: .ForEach() maybe...that is if you want to return the full object instance but with the description cut to 20 letters.

Comment: Do you need both the full description and the short version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var blogPosts = _repo
         .GetPosts()
         .OrderByDescending(o => o.PostedOn)
         .Take(25)
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(x => new BlogPost 
                      { 
                         Description = x.Description.Substring(0, 20)),
                         // set other properties
                      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Iv'e tried this but the variable blogPost now returns Ienumerable<string>. I want it to return as a object. Witch in my case is a IEnumerable<BlogPost>. Hw do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
var blogPosts = _repo.GetPosts()
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.PostedOn)
    .Take(25)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x=>new 
    { 
        x...., //other needed properties
        Description = x.Description.Substring(0,20)
    });
```

Comment: fyi, you need to give names to the properties otherwise `new { x.Description.Substring(0,20) }` won't compile

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the short descriptions, you can just do more LinQ:

```
var shortenedDescriptions = blogPosts.Select(post => post.Description)
                                     .Select(s => s.Substring(0, Math.Min(s.Length, 20))).ToList();
```

If you want to optimize it, you can do the two selects in one go.

If you actually want to *shorten* the descriptions, you will need a loop:

```
foreach(var post in blogPosts)
{
   post.Description = post.Description.Substring(0, Math.Min(s.Length, 20))
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `Math.Min` to protect against strings shorter than 20 chars